# How would I create a matrix in python without importing modules? How would I make a tensor without importing modules?

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to make a matrix and tensor in python without importing any modules such as numpy. Would there be a way to do this?

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is usually "yes" -- you're using a general-purpose language on a general-purpose computer, so you have full Turing potential.  The implied question behind this, "how do I do it?" is an open-ended, individualized tutorial, which is *seriously* off-topic for Stack Overflow -- please re-take the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Prune More than 90% of the questions on stackoverflow can be reworded as "How do I do [X]?" Just because the implied question is of the form "how do I do [X]," does not make the question non-stackoverflow material. Also, there is usually more than one way to do things, which is why people's answers differ so much. If there was only one correct way to do a thing, there would be almost no point in the website's feature to up-vote or down-vote a particular answer.

Comment: It's not "how do I do this"; rather it's posting such a request with no research and no attempt shown.  *These* questions are specifically in need of focus.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is just a list of lists. You can do so as such:

```
x = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

As far as performing operations without numpy goes, that will be up to you to create functions for likely using nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a list of lists, e.g.:

```
matrix = [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
]
```

You would then have to implement all of the mathematical operations (matrix multiplication etc) on top of that data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Python reserves the method name `__matmul__` for matrix multiplication

```
class Matrix:

    def __mul__(left, right):
        print("__mul__ was called")

    def __matmul__(left, right):
        print("__MATMUL__ WAS CALLED")

    def __rmatmul__(right, left):
        print(40*"#")
        print("__rmatmul__")
        print("left == ", left)
        print("right == ", right)
        print(40 * "#")

    def __imatmul__(total, step):
        print("__imatmul__")

a = Matrix()
b = Matrix()

a * b # scalar multiplication __mul__
a @ b # matrix multiplication __matmul__
3 @ b # matrix multiplication __rmatmul__
a @= b
```

---

`__imatmul__` is similar to the following:

```
x = 5
x += 2   # __iadd__(x, 2)   `x = x + 2`
x *= 1   # __imul__(x, 3)   `x = x * 3`
```

---

Whenever you write `x * y` python attempts to get the definition of multiplication from the left-hand argument first. That is, `x * y` is initially `type(x).__add__(x, y)`
However, sometimes the left-hand thing doesn't know how to multiply itself by the right-hand thing.

```
class K:
    pass

a = K()
result = 55*a
result = type(55).__mul__(55, a)
```

The `int` class does not know how to multiply together `55` and an instance of class `K`. If `type(left).__mul__(left, right)` fails, then the back-up mechanism `type(right).__rmul__(right, left)` is called. If you write your own matrix class, then 3  `__rmatmul__` and `__rmul__` are what will be called when you put a scalar multiple out in front, like 88.

```
m = Matrix()
88 * m     # __rmul__(m, 88)
88 @ m     # __rmatmul__(m, 88)
```

---

One way to implement a matrix is as a list of lists:

```
matrix = [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
]
```

This has several notable disadvantages. One is that it is easy to select a row of the matrix:

```
matrix[1] == [0, 1, 0]
```

However, selecting columns would be very inefficient:

```
def get_column(coli:int):
    coli = 1
    column = list()
    for rowi in range(len(matrix)):
        column.append(matrix[rowi][coli])
    return column
```

---

One solution would be to have two different lists of lists:

1. one in "row-major" order.
2. the other in "column-major" order.

```
row_then_col = [
    [[("r0", "c0")], [("r0", "c1")], [("r0", "c2")]],
    [[("r1", "c0")], [("r1", "c1")], [("r1", "c2")]],
    [[("r2", "c0")], [("r2", "c1")], [("r2", "c2")]],
]


ncols = 3
nrows = 3
col_then_row = list()
for coli in range(ncols):
    col_then_row.append([None]*ncols)
    for rowi in range(nrows):
        col_then_row[coli]
        col_then_row[coli][rowi] = row_then_col[rowi][coli]
```

Then `col_then_row[coli]` will return a whole column and `row_then_col[rowi]` will return a whole row. You can fake "pointers" with a list of one element. This is will allow a change in `col_then_row` to automatically be visible in `row_then_col`, a vis versa, without updating anything.

```
row_then_col[1][2][0] = "happy"
print(col_then_row[2][1][0]) # "happy"
```

There are many  [algorithms for matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm). I recommend implementing [Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm). It is not the fastest in the world, but it is easier to understand than the truly fast ones.

There are many ways to implement matrices. The beginnings of one implementation is shown below:

```
import io
import math
import abc

def flatten(container):
    for elem in container:
        if not hasattr(elem, "__iter__"):
            yield elem
        else:
            it_elem = iter(elem)
            subelem = next(it_elem)
            if subelem != elem:
                yield subelem
                for j in flatten(it_elem):
                    yield j


class MatrixNodeState(abc.ABC):
    """
    Abstract Base Class
    """
    pass
MatrixNodeState.MatrixNodeState = MatrixNodeState

class MatrixNodeStateNullNullNullClass(MatrixNodeState):
    @classmethod
    def ERR(cls):
        with io.StringIO() as string_stream:
            print(
                "YOU ARE OFF THE EDGE OF THE MAP!",
                "STOP ITERATING!",
                file=string_stream
            )
            msg = string_stream.getvalue()
        raise cls.OFF_THE_EDGE_OF_THE_MAP(msg)

    class OFF_THE_EDGE_OF_THE_MAP(Exception):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, *args):
        type(self).ERR()

    def __setattr__(self, *args):
        type(self).ERR()
MatrixNodeState.nullnullnull = MatrixNodeStateNullNullNullClass()


class MatrixNodeStateNullNullClass(MatrixNodeState):
    def __setattr__(*args):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, *args):
        return type(self).nullnullnull

MatrixNodeState.nullnull = MatrixNodeStateNullNullClass()

class MatrixNodeStateNullClass(MatrixNodeState):
    """
    This class exists because `None.left = n`
    would produce an error

    `null.left = k` -----`no operation`.
                          Does nothing
                          Does not set the `left` attribute
                          of the nullnull node.

    `x = node.left`  returns `nullnull`
    """
    def __setattr__(*args):
        pass
    def __getattribute__(self, *args):
        return type(self).nullnull
MatrixNodeState.null = MatrixNodeStateNullClass()

class MatrixNodeStateNonNullNull(MatrixNodeState):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data  = data
        self.up    = type(self).null
        self.right = type(self).null
        self.down  = type(self).null
        self.left  = type(self).null
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, type(self).nullnull):
            value = type(self).null
        elif isinstance(value, type(self).nullnullnull):
            value = type(self).null
        super().__setattr__(self, key, value)


MatrixNodeState.MatrixNodeStateNonNullNull = MatrixNodeStateNonNullNull

class MatrixNode:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        MatrixNodeState = type(self)
        if data:
            self.state = MatrixNodeState.MatrixNodeStateNonNullNull(data)
        else:
            self.state = MatrixNodeState.nullnull
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        return self.state.attrname
    def __setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value):
        try:
            object.__getattr__(self)
            super().__setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value)
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(self.state, attr_name, attr_value)

MatrixNode.MatrixNodeState = MatrixNodeState   

class Matrix:
    """

    """
    MatrixNode = MatrixNode

    def __init__(self, xdims, xelems):
        """
        Example 1:
             m = Matrix([3, 3], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
        Example 2
            m = Matrix([3, 3], [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
        """
        MatrixNode = type(self).MatrixNode
        idims = tuple(map(int, xdims))
        ielems = iter(flatten(xelems))
        nrows = idims[0]
        ncols = idims[1]
        self.d = dict()
        try:            
            elem_count = 0
            left_node = MatrixNode.nullnull
            up_node = MatrixNode.nullnull 
            for rowi in range(nrows):
                for coli in range(ncols):
                    ielem = next(ielem)
                    elem_count += 1
                    up_node = left_node.up.right
                    node = MatrixNode(ielem)
                    self.d[(rowi, coli)] = node
                    node.left = left_node
                    left_node.right = node
                    node.up = up_node
                    up_node.down = node
                    left_node = node

        except StopIteration:
            with io.StringIO() as string_stream:
                print(
                    "Dimensions", idims, "indicated",
                    "that there should be", math.prod(idims),
                    "elements.", "Instead, only ", elem_count,
                    "elements were found.",
                    file=string_stream
                )
                msg = string_stream.getvalue()
            raise TypeError(msg)

    def __getitem__(self, xkey):
        ikey = tuple(map(int, iter(flatten(xkey))))
        return self.d[ikey].data

    def __setitem__(self, xkey, xval):
        ikey = tuple(map(int, iter(flatten(xkey))))
        self.d[ikey].data = xval
        return

    def get_column(self, coli):
        coli = int(str(coli))

    def get_row(self, rowi):
        rowi = int(str(rowi))

    def __mul__(left, right):
        print("__mul__ was called")
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __rmul__(right, left):
        """
        m = Matrix([1, 2, 3])
        88 * m
        """
        print("__rmul__ was called")
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __matmul__(left, right):
        print("__MATMUL__ WAS CALLED")
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __rmatmul__(right, left):
        print(40*"#")
        print("__rmatmul__")
        print("left == ", left)
        print("right == ", right)
        print(40 * "#")
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __imatmul__(total, step):
        print("__imatmul__")
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __str__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self) + str(self)


row_then_col = [
    [[("r0", "c0")], [("r0", "c1")], [("r0", "c2")]],
    [[("r1", "c0")], [("r1", "c1")], [("r1", "c2")]],
    [[("r2", "c0")], [("r2", "c1")], [("r2", "c2")]],
]

a = Matrix([3, 3], row_then_col)
```